# Create/Push new local branch to repository based on remote

Tags: git, visual-studio, github, version-control, git-push

Can someone tell me what's wrong with my action? I'm trying to create a new branch off a remote branch, and push the new branch to my repository.

```
Description:
-Currently on branch "test"
-git pull
-git checkout -b <new_branch_name> origin/test
```

I confirmed my branch was switched to the new branch. However, when I commit/pushed my changes through visual studio the new branch was NOT created and the changes were pushed to the remote "origin/test".

On the contrary, if I run the checkout command without the second parameter "origin/test" (while still currently on the origin/test branch) and then I execute git push, my new branch is created

Why is this occurring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### TL;DR

It's because the upstream of your new branch is set to `origin/test`.  Visual Studio apparently (mis)uses this to decide to ask the remote to update its `test` branch.

#### Important background

Branches are not created from branches.  Branches are created from *commits*.  It's important to know and understand this; if you think that branches mean something in Git, you will eventually hurt yourself.  It's like assuming that a 1980s-era automobile has self-driving capability.

#### Upstreams

That said, each branch, in Git, *can* have one *upstream* set.  A branch either has an upstream set, or does not have an upstream set.  To set a particular upstream, use `git branch --set-upstream-to`:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/somebranch
```

for instance.  The current branch now has `origin/somebranch` set as its upstream (unless the command failed, in which case nothing has changed).  If it previously had `origin/otherbranch` set as its upstream, that upstream is now removed, because only one upstream can be set: `origin/somebranch` is now the upstream.

To *unset* the upstream, use `git branch --unset-upstream`:

```
git branch --unset-upstream
```

The current branch now has no upstream.  If it had no upstream before, this operation does nothing; otherwise, it removes the upstream setting.

The upstream of a branch is:

- another (local) branch name, or
- a remote-tracking name like `origin/somebranch`.

In *command line Git*, the behavior `git push`, with no additional arguments, is controlled by the `push.default` setting.  If this is set to `simple`—as it normally is today—this kind of `git push` will only push to the upstream of the current branch, and only if the upstream is set to a remote-tracking name that—once the remote part is removed—matches the current branch.

For example, suppose the current branch is named `br1`, and both `origin/br1` and `origin/br2` exist.  If we run:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/br2
git push
```

we will get an error from `git push` because the name `br2` in `origin/br2` does not match the name `br1`.  However, if we then run:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/br1
git push
```

the `git push` will this time call up `origin` and attempt to have the Git repository at `origin` update that other Git repository's branch `br1` (the branch on the other Git that we remember, locally, as `origin/br1`).

#### Branch creation and upstream settings

When we choose to create a new branch—with `git branch`, `git checkout -b`, or `git switch -c`—we must give Git two things:

1. Git needs the *name* of the new branch it should create.
2. Git needs the *hash ID* of some *existing commit*.  The newly created branch will point to this existing commit.

The *default* hash ID, if we do not give Git one, is the hash ID of the *current commit* (as found by the *current branch name* in most cases).  That is, if we have run `git checkout test` so that the current branch name is `test`, and we run:

```
git rev-parse test
```

and

```
git rev-parse HEAD
```

we will get the same hash ID from both operations.  That's because the special name `HEAD` is *attached to* the branch name `test`, and the branch name `test` points to the commit whose hash ID both `git rev-parse` commands print.

We can draw this setup like this:

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <-- test (HEAD)
```

That is, the *name* `test` *points to* some commit with some hash ID, drawn here as `H`, which stands for "hash".  Every commit in Git has both a snapshot and metadata, and the metadata in a commit contain a list of previous commit hash IDs, usually just one entry long.  In this case commit `H` contains the hash ID of—i.e., "points to"—some earlier commit, whose hash ID we're just calling `G`.  (The real hash ID, in each case, is some big ugly random-looking string of letters and digits.)  Commit `G` has a snapshot and metadata, and thereby points to still-earlier commit `F`, which has a snapshot and metadata, and so on.

When we ask Git to create a *new* branch name, with `git checkout -b newbr` in this case, Git will:

1. create the new name, pointing to the selected commit—in this case commit `H`—and then
2. attach `HEAD` to the new name.

We can draw the result like this:

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <-- newbr (HEAD), test
```

That is, *both branch names point to the same commit* (whose hash ID is `H`).

**When we use this form of branch creation, the new branch has no upstream set.**  So `newbr` has *no* upstream.  A command-line `git push` will, with the defaults in modern Git, give us an error; we will have to run `git push -u origin newbr` or `git push -u origin HEAD` to create a name `newbr` over on `origin` so that our Git will create `origin/newbr` locally, so that we have an `origin/newbr` to have as an upstream.  The `-u` option to `git push` will then immediately *set* that as the upstream.

**Visual Studio apparently behaves differently.**  If no upstream is set, VS apparently just runs `git push origin newbr:newbr`, rather than giving us an error.

You can, however, *tell* Git, at the time you *create* a branch, to set its upstream *right then*.  To do so, you *must* use the form in which you give Git a specific commit by name rather than by raw hash ID:

```
git checkout -b newbr origin/test
```

for instance.  **This is what you are doing.**  When you use this form of `git checkout -b` or `git switch -c` or `git branch`, Git will, by default:

1. use the name `origin/test` to find a commit hash ID;
2. create the new branch name `newbr` pointing to this commit; and
3. set the upstream of `newbr` to `origin/test`.

Note this extra step 3, that *does not* occur when using `git checkout -b newbr` without that additional argument.

In command-line Git, this choice—to create a new branch *with* an upstream set—is actually controllable via multiple options:

- The `-t` or `--track` option says ***do** do this*.
- The `--no-track` options says ***do not** do this*.
- The configuration setting `branch.autoSetupMerge` says whether to do this, in which cases, when `-t` or `--no-track` is not specified.

The description I've given above covers the normal behavior when `branch.autoSetupMerge` is *not* set, or is set to `true`.  You can set it to `false`, in which case branch creation options always act as if `--no-track` were specified, and you can set it to `always`, which makes Git set a *local* branch as the upstream of a new branch when you provide a local branch name as the starting point.

You probably should not set this option, and simply avoid giving `git branch` a starting name, or use the `--no-track` option:

```
git checkout -b newbr $(git rev-parse origin/test)
```

or:

```
git checkout -b newbr --no-track origin/test
```

Both methods will avoid setting any upstream for the new branch.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to write such an in-depth description - I definitely learned a couple things